# How to call functions through a href in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have `jsp` code where i fetch data from database in a `resultset` and pass it in `a href`. When i click on link i call a function from `<script>`. Only problem is when i click on the link the result comes and goes. It doesn't stop at that page. Can anyone help me to solve this. My `jsp` code is:

```
<%@include file="dbconnection.jsp"%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    </TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1></H1>
    <script>


function displayData(ctr) {
       //////// Here i want to display data related to that particular link


switch (ctr) {
case 1:

    <%ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select CID from categoryConfigTable where parentCID = 'NULL';") ;  %>
    <% 
    int c=0;
     while(rs.next()){ 
        String link=rs.getString(1);
        c++;
    %>
    document.write('<A HREF = "#" ONCLICK="abc(<%=c%>)"><%=link%></A>');
    <% } %>
    document.write('<button onclick="goBack()"> Go Back </button>');

    function goBack() {
        window.history.back()
    }

    break;
case 2:
   alert("function 2");
     break;

     }
}


</script>
 <TABLE>
           <%ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select DISTINCT title from categoryInfoTable where CID in(select CID from categoryConfigTable where parentCID = 'NULL');") ;%>
            <% 
            int counter=0;
             while(resultset.next()){ 
                String link=resultset.getString(1);
                counter++;
            %>
            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a onclick="displayData(<%=counter%>)" href="#"><%=link%></a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>
            <% } %>
  </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The write() method is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML. Try following code:

```
<%@include file="dbconnection.jsp"%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    </TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1></H1>
    <script>


function displayData(ctr) {
       //////// Here i want to display data related to that particular link


switch (ctr) {
case 1:

    <%ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select CID from categoryConfigTable where parentCID = 'NULL';") ;  %>
    <% 
    int c=0;
     while(rs.next()){ 
        String link=rs.getString(1);
        c++;
    %>
    $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF = "#" ONCLICK="abc(<%=c%>)"><%=link%></A>');
    <% } %>
    $('#myDiv').append('<button onclick="goBack()"> Go Back </button>');

    function goBack() {
        window.history.back()
    }

    break;
case 2:
   alert("function 2");
     break;

     }
}


</script>
 <TABLE>
           <%ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select DISTINCT title from categoryInfoTable where CID in(select CID from categoryConfigTable where parentCID = 'NULL');") ;%>
            <% 
            int counter=0;
             while(resultset.next()){ 
                String link=resultset.getString(1);
                counter++;
            %>
            <TR>
               <TD>
                   <a onclick="displayData(<%=counter%>)" href="#"><%=link%></a>
               </TD> 
            </TR>
            <% } %>
  </TABLE>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate or explain with an example because i am new to jsp

Comment: can you use jquery in your code ?.. if yes then replace document.write with $('anyEmptyDivContainer').append() method. Try this if you get any problem then you can ask.. !!

Comment: I request you to please show me it in code i am literally new to jsp and jquery as well

Comment: please communicate in the comments. Don't edit the answer if you want to say something. and try to debug yourself and see exactly what type of error you are getting in case two. Is it script error or logical error i.e you result set is proper or not . Find out that first and tell me here.

Comment: my query is right i am getting error in console as java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Comment: Your Resultset Object is getting closed and after that you are attempting to access the ResultSet. in your code. Try to find that in your code.

Comment: But i am creating new resulset object and if what you are telling is true then at least my first link which was working previously should work

Comment: is your query returning any row??

Comment: Yes its returning multiple rows

Comment: Edit you question with fresh code with what you are writing in case 2

Comment: I tried to run the code which you have pasted here and it is not throwing any SQLException. So check your full code.

Comment: when i click on one link i want that previous links should be disabled and only results related to the link should be visible